# How to add UI elements (like "picker") to View dynamically in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, ios, visual-studio, xamarin

[image: This is my view in the app which I created.]

[image: With a add buton I want to add UI element. For this case it is a picker like in the third image.]

[image: It is for adding multiple group to single user.]

As I mentinoned in image `discriptions`, I have update register form and I want to update groups of my User, But for now I can do that with just one group. I should be able to add this User to multiple groups. For that I need multiple Pickers and like in the images I need to pop up pickers in the screen dynamically according to needs of the User. Maybe the User will want to select one group or maybe want to three groups.

What I am asking here is, How can I add this pickers or any UI element dynamically while app is running. And last question is, user can ,maybe, want to remove that second or third picker from the view. Deselect I mean. How can I do that. **Thanks for ideas and codes.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many solutions which can implement it .  For example you can check the following code .

#### 1. create a custom view  which contains the Picker

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="xxx.PickerView">
  <ContentView.Content>

        <Grid HeightRequest="40">

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.9*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*" />

            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Picker Grid.Column="0" x:Name="picker" Title="Select Groups" TitleColor="Red"  />

            <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="Canel" TextColor="Red">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />

                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
            </Label>

        </Grid>

    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace xxx
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class PickerView : ContentView
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> pickerSource { get; set; }

        //public PickerView()
        //{
        //    InitializeComponent();
        //}

        public PickerView(ObservableCollection<string> source)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            picker.ItemsSource = source;
        }

        private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var stack = this.Parent as StackLayout;

            stack.Children.Remove(this);
        }
    }
}
```

#### in content page

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

    <StackLayout x:Name="pickerStack" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        
        
        
    </StackLayout>

    <Button Text="+ add another group" Clicked="Button_Clicked" />

</StackLayout>
```

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var source = new ObservableCollection<string>() {"111","222","333" };

   pickerStack.Children.Add(new PickerView(source));
}
```

[image]

Comment: I want to ask another question. How can I access these every picker that user created. For example user will choose 3 group and I should know which ones are selected.

Comment: They are different questions , you could create a new thread with more details so that I could help you better .

Comment: OK, I will check it tomorrow :)