# How I can access to selected parameters inside the multiple Xamarin "Picker"

Tags: c#, android, ios, visual-studio, xamarin

I created a custom picker with the help of  Lucas Zhang which you can check in the link
[xamarin custom multiple picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59486847/how-to-add-ui-elements-like-picker-to-view-dynamically-in-xamarin)

Now I have another question with this problem. When user select a group or groups, I need access to these selected parameters.

```
public class Grup
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SubsID { get; set; }
}
```

This is the model I use. Picker reads Groupnames through ViewModel which is shown below.

```
public class NewUserViewModel
{
    public List<Grup> GroupList { get; set; }
    public List<Grup> SelectedGroup { get; set; }
}
```

And I want save these parameters which came from every pickers in the view to here and furthermore I will send them to database through API.Question is how can I access these IDs when user select them and click save button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to do this is to listen for picker's selection events and then get the result of each selection by iterating over the `pickerStack`

like this(base on Lucas Zhang's sample):

in **PickerView** :

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class PickerView : ContentView
{
    public Group SelectGroup; // add the SelectGroup property which save the result after you select
    public ObservableCollection<Group> pickerSource { get; set; }

    public PickerView(ObservableCollection<Group> source) //here i change the source to your Group model
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        picker.ItemsSource = source;
    }

    private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var stack = this.Parent as StackLayout;

        stack.Children.Remove(this);
    }

    private void picker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var picker = sender as Picker;
        SelectGroup = (Group)picker.SelectedItem;    
    }
}
```

in **PickerView.xaml** just add the `SelectedIndexChanged` event:

```
<Picker Grid.Column="0" x:Name="picker" Title="{Binding GroupName}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding ID}"  TitleColor="Red"  SelectedIndexChanged="picker_SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

in your page :

```
public partial class MutiPicker : ContentPage
{
    public MutiPicker()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var source = new ObservableCollection<Group>() { new Group() { ID=111,GroupName="AAA",SubsID=1}, new Group() { ID = 222, GroupName = "BBB", SubsID = 2 }, new Group() { ID = 333, GroupName = "CCC", SubsID = 3 } };

        pickerStack.Children.Add(new PickerView(source));
    }

    //iterate over your pickerviews
    private void Update_Clicker(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var pickerview in pickerStack.Children)
        {

            if (pickerview is PickerView && ((PickerView)pickerview).SelectGroup != null)
            {
                var selectgroup = ((PickerView)pickerview).SelectGroup;//here you will get your select group,then you could get its ID ,GroupName or SubsID 
            }

        }
    }
}
```